# Proper Quoting in Bash: Attach numbers stored in i to a

Tags: linux, bash

I wanted to write a short shell script, which removes specified pages from a pdf. Maybe I'm doing that in a bit convoluted manner, but that is what I came up with so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This is a script to remove a specified page from a specified pdf.
set verbose

s="A1-$(($2-1))"

if [ n -ge 3 ]; then
      for i in 2..$#
      do      
            s+=A$(($($i)+1))-$(($($(($i+1)))-1))
      done 
fi
pdftk A="$1" cat $s A$(($($#)+1))-end output output.pdf
```

I know it's quite convoluted code and if you know about the working of pdftk, I would appreciate a hint to make it easier, but for now I just need to know how to substitute a variable into a variable name. E.g. if

```
i=2
a2=3
echo $a($i)
```

gave me `3`, that would be great, but it doesn't. How do I achieve this?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html

Comment: Can you give an *concrete* example of the input to your script and the set of pages you would want put in the output? Your pseudo-code is nearly impossible to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` allows indirect parameter expansion:

```
$ i=2
$ a2=3
$ var="a$i"  # a2
$ echo "${!var}"
3
```

What you really seem to want, though, is an array:

```
$ a=([2]=3)    # Or simply a[2]=3
$ i=2
$ echo "${a[i]}"
3
```

(This is really a stop-gap answer, as there is almost certainly a much simpler answer to your question that doesn't involve this type of indirect parameter manipulation.)

---

I think this much simpler script that will do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

inputfile=$1
shift

ranges=() from=1
for pageToOmit in "$@"; do
    ranges+=( "A$from-$(( pageToOmit - 1))" )
    from=$(( pageToOmit + 1 ))
done
ranges+=( "$from-end" )

pdftk A="$inputfile" cat "${ranges[@]}" output output.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Using eval:

```
i=2
a2=3
eval echo \$a$i
eval b=\$a$i
echo $b
```